# jQuery select-box: getting the text when #id not known

Tags: jquery

From jquery docs:

```
$( "#myselect" ).val();
```

Will give the value and for text following will suffice:

```
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
```

How can text be extracted when all one has is the `this` reference?

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".lots-of-select-boxes-class", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var text = HOW-TO-GET-TEXT; // ???      
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
var text =$(this).find("option:selected").text();
```

or

[.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
var text =$(this).children("option:selected").text();
```

---

[this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: @C-link he want text of option not the value .

Comment: Option has value not text.

Comment: @C-link Are you sure `<option value="val">Text</option>` ?

Comment: Oh! Sorry. My mistake.